# Acesso externo Phonegap

Tags: apache-cordova

Problema : meu app roda legal no emulador porem quando gero o .apk ele nao acessa internet.

Obs: Não alterei nada em config.xml e no androidManifests.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ezequiel, o PhoneGap na sua própria documentação possui uma explicação detalhada referente ao acesso de internet pelo Aplicativo. Segue o link:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#supported-cordova-platforms

Recomendo que leia, pois é de grande auxilio.

Execute os seguintes comandos no seu terminal, no diretório de seu aplicativo:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
$ cordova prepare
```

(Se for windows, não precisa do $)

E adicione a seguinte linha no seu `config.xml`:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Essa linha, basicamente te dá a autorização para acessar todas paginas da internet através do seu aplicativo.

NOTA: No seu `config.xml`, verifique se possui qualquer outra tag `<allow-navigation>`, se tiver, pode excluir ela e copiar a que eu passei em cima.